# Set Apache as a Forward proxy on VPS with SSL

Tags: reactjs, apache, express, .htaccess, vps

I have a React app with express server listening port 3000 deployed on VPS (which has some IP 123.123.123.123) with Apache. Also I have SSL setup.
The problem I have is that on page refresh/direct path entering I'm getting 404 error. But everything is working fine once I set example.com:3000/page.
At the moment I have .htaccess file with this setup:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Which redirects to https.

I need forward proxy setup to be done correctly to port 3000.

Any help with this setup will be very helpful as I'm stuck with the development.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You will need to setup a reverse proxy on your Apache to redirect traffic on port 443 to port 3000. It can be done by adding the following lines in your Apache config

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://0.0.0.0:3000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://0.0.0.0:3000/
```

Comment: Reverse Proxy or Forward Proxy?

Comment: Also, can I just add those rows in the end of config or how it should look like? ex. like:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://0.0.0.0:3000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://0.0.0.0:3000/

Comment: Just adding those 3 lines to the end of config broke it.

Comment: For reverse proxy, you need to add it in your apache config file and not in .htaccess. If you want to put in .htaccess, you can add this instead: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}:3000/$1 [P]

Comment: Changed .htaccess file scrypt to:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}:3000/$1 [P] and it is not working (still geting 404 of page refresh)

Comment: Please suggest if the httpd.conf file should include <VirtualHost *:443> ProxyPreserveHost On ProxyRequests Off ServerName example.com ServerAlias www.example.com ProxyPass / http://0.0.0.0:3000/ ProxyPassReverse / http://0.0.0.0:3000/ </VirtualHost> or it's incorrect?